# Can I get a list of RGB colors from a graphics object?

Tags: plotting, color

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the list of `RGBColor` from a plot.

What I mean is simple. Suppose I plot list L with "TemperatureMap":

```
L={1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10};
P1=ListPlot[L,ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"]]
```

Getting a simple plot:

[image]

Can I retrieve from the graphics object `P1`, the list of `RGBColor` elements used? (i.e. the color values for each dot in the `ListPlot`)

colorList= {RGBcolor[],...,RGBcolor[]}

Thanks!

Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coordsandcolors = DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[P1, GraphicsComplex[coords_, __, 
   VertexColors -> colors_] :> Transpose[{coords, RGBColor @@@ colors}], All][[1]]

Grid[coordsandcolors]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I must admit I don't quite understand how this works, but it does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is worth to note that `ListPlot` behaves this way only in version 12.0. In version 11.3 it produces a plot with all the points of identical color. And in version 12.0 we have a bug: applying `Normal` changes the plot to the previous version's styling (just removes `VertexColors` information).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, excellent points. (Actually, `Normal[P1]` was my first try.)